# Rails 3 nested forms with has_many :through, entry in join table doesn't get deleted after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, join

I have a 'User' model which has a has_many relationship to a 'Number' model through a join table 'user_number' model.
I use:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :numbers, :allow_destroy => true
```

in the 'User' model. Everything works fine except that whenever I delete a number from a user in the edit form,
the associated number is deleted correctly in the 'number' table, but not the entry in the 'user_number' join table.

In the update controller action I only use this:

```
...
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
...
```

How can I force rails to also delete the associated entry in the join table?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have User accepts_nested_attributes_for :join_class, :allow_destroy => true. Then, you delete the association. The idea behind a has_many :through is that you don't delete the m part of the n->m mapping unless there are no other associations left..

Comment: @Hadi S. - If this worked for you, could you please upvote and mark as correct?